# Angular 15 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10?

Tags: nginx, dockerfile

I have deployed angular file with docker and nginx file but from harness pipeline CI done but CD got issue and in the CD i have added my nginx file as well as error image can anybody help on that regarding that issue i am stuck this issue last 4 days can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance[image]

nginx file

```js
# #worker_threads to run;
# "auto" sets it to the #CPU_cores available in the system, and
# offers the best performance.
worker_processes    auto;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024;
 }

http {
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    256M;

    # Brotli Settings
    # brotli on;
    # brotli_comp_level 4;
    # brotli_buffers 32 8k;
    # brotli_min_length 100;
    # brotli_static on;
    # brotli_types image/jpeg image/bmp image/svg+xml text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon;


    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #added for security issues
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        #added for security issues
        proxy_pass_header Server;

        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
}
```

```
Docker File


  FROM node:16 AS builder
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install --max-old-space-size=4096
    COPY . .
    RUN npm run build -- --base-href /ui/ --configuration=development
    
    FROM nginx:alpine
    COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
    # Copy the nginx conf that we created to the container
    COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 1week i have fixed above issue issue inside/etc/nginx/nginx.conf path :

```
Change from
COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

to 
COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```